# PHP check if an array starts with specific value and ends with specific value,

Tags: php, arrays, object

Is there a clean elegant way to check if an array object value that has specific value  "positionID = string(29)" and if its "Action" starts with for eg "(string) 1" and ends with "(string) 0".

The unlooped array looks similar to this

```
array (
   [0] => Object1 {
            ['PositionID'] => (string) 29
            ['Action'] => (string) 1
          }
   [1] => Object22 {
            ['PositionID'] => (string) 30
            ['Action'] => (string) 0
          }
   [2] => Object23 {
            ['PositionID'] => (string) 29
            ['Action'] => (string) 1
          }

   [3] => Object5 {
            ['PositionID'] => (string) 31
            ['Action'] => (string) 0
          }
   [2] => Object23 {
            ['PositionID'] => (string) 29
            ['Action'] => (string) 0
          }
);
```

I would like to find out within that array that the last "Action" occurence of "positionID= 29" is 0 or something else. At the moment I am grouping the positionId and storing them into a third array and looping it which feels like a dirty solution to me.

Comment: Do you mean the last element - or is it the last element for a specific positionID( so for positionID = 31, this is element 3)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`end()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php). First item should be obvious.

```
$first = $array[0];
if ($first->positionId === '29' && $first->Action === '1') {
    $last = end($array);
    if ($last->positionId === '29' && $last->Action === '0' {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$items = 
[
    [
        'position' => '17',
        'action' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'position' => '47',
        'action' => '0'
    ],
    [
        'position' => '23',
        'action' => '0'
    ]
];

foreach ($items as $k => $item)
    $items[$k] = (object) $item;

var_dump($items);

if(array_column($items, 'action', 'position')[23] === '0')
    echo "Action is '0' for the object with position 23";
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["position"]=>
      string(2) "17"
      ["action"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["position"]=>
      string(2) "47"
      ["action"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["position"]=>
      string(2) "23"
      ["action"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  Action is '0' for the object with position 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and you [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to return the last item from the array `$result`:

```
$result = array_column(array_filter($arrays, function ($x) {
    return $x->PositionID === '29';
}), 'Action');
$lastValue = end($result);
var_dump($lastValue);
```

That would give you:

```
string(1) "0"
```

Then you might use it like:

```
if ($lastValue === "0") {
    // ...
}
```